# What rituals should be used by oracles?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process

I am creating a role-playing game([LARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_action_role-playing_game)) where rituals are actually performed in real life.

The spells are probably going to be created in advance because one can imaging that all following systems are very constrainless magic systems. The game is in the very early stage of development, so there are even no plot yet and the setting is unspecified, but the question itself is not depending on the setting or plot, so here it is.

There are three types of magic practitioners in the game:

- Shamans, inspiration is taken from the Sympathetic Magic chapter of [The Golden Bough, by Frazer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Bough)

They are practicing spell casting by doing something that is similar to what they are wanting to achieve. For example: if some shaman wants to steal something, he will throw some grave dirt on the roof of the house he wants to steal from for the inhabitants to sleep like the dead and not to catch him.

Such things sound ridiculous, but there is plenty of room to create new rituals or adapt existing ones.

- Kabbalists, inspiration is taken from my vague understanding of the idea that the words and symbols have the literal power to create something they mean.

The idea of rituals is that there is a combination of symbols and geometric figures that literally mean the effect of the spell. So casting spells is just creating these symbols on a piece of paper, or on the ground and saying out loud some words to fill missing parameters. The example is as follows.

Let's assume that spell is to create food out of thin air. Given the figure to draw, the parameters are the type of food you want. Once you drew a figure and said that you want rice with curry it would be created. The quality of the food will be dependant on the precision of your drawings and the amount is determent by the size of it.

As one can imagine creating magic is quite simple here. There are many geometrical figures to put inside one another to create a sophisticated picture that is fun to draw.

- Oracles, the ones that can look through the future.

I have no idea where to take inspiration from. The obvious is that [Pythia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia) is a good example of the oracle, but there are no rituals. She just sits on a big chair and talks.

I want to find some framework for oracles to create interesting spells and rituals inside it. The important quality is that this framework should be disconnected from other types of magic and be standalone practice.

---

EDIT: To clarify what is the answer I am looking for: I am looking for a religion or belief system(real or fictional) with rituals for predicting the future that are relying neither on sympathetic magic nor on words, symbols, or drawings to make predictions.

A good example is Christianity(no spells at all, only prayers), but they are not predicting the future, so it is a misfit.

Comment: Why not take inspiration from divination rituals present in wicca and other such witchcrafts?

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. I have never heard of it. Thank you

Comment: Asking for a framework for creating interesting rituals, seems like a very broad ask. Each LARP I've been have had their own framework for spells, hell some LARPS have used different frameworks for different thematic styles of magic. Unfortunately questions like this with many valid answers are too broad for this site and likely to be closed. Do you have a more specific question about building *your* framework you want to ask?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? Am I correct in understanding that you are interested in references and real-world examples for creating oracles' rituals?

Comment: @Otkin, the real-world example is good because it is usually very deep due to the time spent by humans designing it in the past. That is why the first two systems are inherited from real-world examples. If you have something in mind that is fictional it is very fine. :)

Comment: @sphennings, I am looking for some environment for creating rituals for oracles. It might be religion or something similar or some fictional system where it is easy to create rituals(by altering existing ones for example). This question might look like it does not have a specific answer, but in my opinion, it does.

Comment: You're always welcome to [edit] your post to clarify your intent and make it come across as less broad. Just telling me that your opinion is that it has a specific answer does little to address the concerns I've raised. To reiterate them; 1. It seems like any system for easily creating rituals is a valid answer to this question. 2. From personal experience there are many systems to create rituals. 3. Questions with many valid answers are too broad for this site.

Comment: I know you mentioned no symbols and no drawings, but why not tarot? There are plenty of examples that you can use from [videogames](https://ogrebattlesaga.fandom.com/wiki/Tarot_Cards) to [tabletop RPGs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177969/tarot-based-rpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Augury**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augury

> Augury is the practice from ancient Roman religion of interpreting
> omens from the observed behavior of birds. When the individual, known
> as the augur, interpreted these signs, it is referred to as "taking
> the auspices". 'Auspices' is from the Latin auspicium and auspex,
> literally "one who looks at birds."[1] Depending upon the birds, the
> auspices from the gods could be favorable or unfavorable (auspicious
> or inauspicious)..
>
> This type of omen reading was already a millennium old in the time of
> Classical Greece: in the fourteenth-century BC diplomatic
> correspondence preserved in Egypt called the "Amarna correspondence",
> the practice was familiar to the king of Alasia in Cyprus who needed
> an 'eagle diviner' to be sent from Egypt.[4]

This seems more practical for a LARP than divination by examination of entrails or the liver, and more action packed than tea leaves.  In outdoor settings there are usually birds around.

Maybe you can read up on augury and what sort of birds mean what, and then codify that for your players.  I might imagine buzzards mean they need to move around more, and seagulls mean that they are eating lunch.